# How to make the table in such format

Tags: tables

[image: Table]
The code

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{}
\caption*{Comparison between the series solution $[y_{1}(x)]$ and $y_{2}(x)]$ and exact solution $[y_{01}(x)]$ and $y_{02}(x)]$ for $\mu{} = 2.0$, $\varepsilon{} = 10^{−7}$.}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{x}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$y_{1}(x)$}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$y_{01}(x)$}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$y_{2}(x)$}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$y_{02}(x)$}   \\
\midrule
&-0.000645   &-0.000645   &-0.000645   \\
&  (-0.83)   &  (-0.83)   &  (-0.39)   \\
&     5035   &     5035   &     5035   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: In case you want the numbers to be aligned at their decimal points, use the package `siunitx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Use a `threeparttable` environment to ensure that the caption occupies the same width as the associated `tabular` environment.
- Use the `caption` package (and a `\captionsetup` instruction) to (re)format the caption.
- Make sure all columns of the `tabular` environment are automatically in math mode, and use the `dcolumn` package so that the numbers are aligned on their respective decimal markers.
- Optional (and not implemented in the answer shown below): If the tables (and, presumably, the rest of the document) need to be typeset using the Times (New) Roman font family, I suggest you also load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,threeparttable,dcolumn}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false,skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}}{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Comparison between the series solution $[y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)]$ 
    and exact solution $[y_{01}(x)$ and $y_{02}(x)]$, for $\mu= 2.0$ 
    and $\varepsilon= 10^{−7}$.}
\begin{tabular}{L d{2.8} L *{2}{d{2.5}} }
\toprule
x & \mc{y_{1}(x)} & y_{01}(x) & \mc{y_{2}(x)} & \mc{y_{02}(x)} \\
\midrule
0.0 & -4.89{\times}10^{-7} & 0.0 & 1.00000 & 1.00000 \\
0.2 & 0.20000              & 0.2 & 0.95948 & 0.95948 \\
\vdots \\ 
1-\varepsilon & \mc{1-\varepsilon} & 1-\varepsilon & -7.31833 & -7.31776\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```